# What is a solution to using the scanning of a QR code to execute a smart contract function on Ethereum?

Tags: qr-code, ethereum, smartcontracts

So I have been working with Ethereum's metamask, and implemented web app where the user can come while being logged into metamask, and call a function on my smart contract via metamask. Tutorials for this exist and it's not very hard.

I want to implement calling a smart contract, when a user comes into a store ([physically). I want to do it the following way:

- Some customer comes in and uses some application $A on his phone, which may be a wallet app or some other application that has access to his ethereum wallet.
- On my POS application, I will render a QR code.
- When he scans the QR code with his mobile phone, it is equivalent to either:

  - sending ethereum funds to our company account, while I am able to verify that this has happened via an event, or
  - he calls a function on a smart contract. This seems more appealing because I know that you can send events via smart contract calls.

So my question is:

- Do any applications that have the functionality of application $A exist, are they widely used?
- What can I use to implement exposing a QR code which is effectively some form of visual API for my program?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a library in your application to create a QR code. This QR code will need to be created for the function/method you need to call on the smart contract. You can use https://github.com/jibrelnetwork/ethereum-qr-code/blob/master/README.md

The QR code will be scanned by the user using the wallet on their mobile phone app wallet. This transaction will trigger the smart contract function and allow your application to proceed forward.

Hope this helps.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Answer to Q1:
Yes, there are applications like this(i made one myself). Most existing mobile wallets use this approach, for eg. [Tenx](https://www.tenx.tech/).

Answer to Q2:
Sorry but this question is not totally clear to me. Are you asking for some sort of library for creating a QR code?